# How can I add appointments to the calendar programmatically in a Windows 8 app?

Tags: xaml, windows-8, calendar

I am developing a Windows 8 C#/XAML app through which I would like to add appointments to calendar.

1. How can I add appointments to my through code?
2. How can I access calender API's?
3. What are the various options available to add appointments?

Comment: Looks like it's not supported: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/hr/messengerconnect/thread/370c5f14-37ee-489d-ba21-3b46ff024798

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [AppointmentManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.appointments.appointmentmanager.aspx) class to work with the calendar & [ShowAddApointmentAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn297264.aspx) method will allow you to add to the calendar.

Answer (score -2):

There are none directly.  The calendar is displaying entries from services like Hotmail, Google or Exchange.  You would have to use one of those APIs to add an entry to the particular calendar that the user is using.  Here is the [API for the Hotmail calendar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh826535) for example.

Comment: It's a nice aside to point out that since the introduction of the Universal App, the Calendar and Contact API have consolidated into one reusable approach. Regardless of the service providing the calendar, Windows and Phone give developers and single point of entry to add/read appointments and contacts.